# PCB trace impedance test measure

Tags: pcb, impedance, trace

I have PCBA for which I want to measure the loop impedance between the power connector and gnd ones. How can I do this test if the passive elements, IC and other elements already attached on the PCB?

Comment: Welcome! Is there any chance to remove the components? Otherwise you will also measure the path through the components.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [smart tweezers](https://www.smarttweezers.us/) or other LCR meter that inject an AC frequency and calculate Z_total between the probes from this. This only works if the branch impedance's are significantly higher at higher impedance. The hard part is deducing what the circuit value is. Try different frequencies also.  I've used this to calculate capacitance better, it might be harder for series resistance.

The next best way is estimation, PCB copper is usually easy to estimate it's properties, even cross capacitance between planes. Use a tool like [Saturn PCB tool](https://saturnpcb.com/saturn-pcb-toolkit/) to estimate these properties. Remember that all copper has series resistance and inductance. Two conductors running in parallel have cross inductance and the electric field between any two conductors has capacitance (with capacitance finding out if it's a problem is usually the case, which you don't usually have to worry about pFs or fFs until you get into the GHz range)